# I want to say to someone that his blog's posts contents quality is increasing day by day

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct grammatically?

> 1. The **content** of your posts **are** enriching day by day.
> 2. The **contents** of your posts **are** enriching day by day.
> 3. The **content** of your posts **is** enriching day by day.

Should I use a plural verb or singular verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb should agree with the main noun. The main noun is "content" or "contents", and the verb should agree with that. The second and third sentence have the correct agreement.

This rule is sometimes broken when a singular noun is used to refer to a group, for example, "Chelsea are going to win the cup".

There are other problems with your sentence: It says "the content enriches (something)" This doesn't make sense. It is not the content which is acting, it is the author.

So try:

> Day by day, you are continuing to enrich the content of your posts.

But even this is odd, since it suggests the author is reworking old posts to enrich them.

> The quality of your posts is improving day by day

or very simply

> Your blog posts are getting better.

Answer (score 0):

The word "content" refers to the whole information contained in something and it's plural form "contents" refer to the things contained in something. Content is uncountable whereas contents are countable. So in your case the last sentence would be grammatically correct i.e.,

> The content of your posts is enriching day by day.